# ruby gem `grpc` does not connect to service connected by `grpcurl` command line

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl, grpc

Our gRPC service requires a client cert.  We can connect with grpcurl but with the `grpc` gem it does not connect with error status 14, as below.

> GRPC::Unavailable (14:failed to connect to all addresses. debug_error_string:{"created":"@1624559541.881757000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624559541.881752000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]})

The grpcurl call is:

> grpcurl -cacert ca.crt -cert client.crt -key client.key -proto service-tess.proto -d '{"app_info":{"device_id":"blah","product_id":"blah","product_family":"blah","product_version":"blah"},"search_string":"cisco.com"}' grpc-server.cisco.com:443 Talos.Service.TESS/WhoisQuery

our call from ruby looks like this:

```
@ca_cert ||= File.open(Rails.configuration.tess.ca_cert_file).read
@cert ||= File.open(Rails.configuration.tess.client_cert_file).read
@cert_key ||= File.open(Rails.configuration.tess.pkey_file).read
@creds ||= GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new(@ca_cert, @cert_key, @cert)
@remote_stub ||= Talos::Service::TESS::Stub.new("grpc-server:443", creds)
whois_search_request = Talos::TESS::WhoisSearchRequest.new(app_info: get_app_info, search_string: name)
response = @remote_stub.whois_query(whois_search_request)
```

The version of the `grpc` gem is `1.38.0 universal-darwin`.

The certs we are using are x509 v1.

The client host uses Catalina macOS `10.15.7`.

**EDIT:**

From setting these environment variables (from [gRPC environment variables](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md)):

```
GRPC_TRACE=all
GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
```

Error output possibly reveals ALPN problem.

```
D0625 13:26:57.543500000 123145470926848 security_handshaker.cc:183]   Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1624642017.543487000","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":162}
I0625 13:26:57.543529000 123145470926848 handshaker.cc:88]             handshake_manager 0x7fe314dce650: error={"created":"@1624642017.543487000","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":162} shutdown=0 index=2, args={endpoint=(nil), args=(nil) {size=0: }, read_buffer=(nil) (length=0), exit_early=0}
I0625 13:26:57.543536000 123145470926848 handshaker.cc:121]            handshake_manager 0x7fe314dce650: handshaking complete -- scheduling on_handshake_done with error={"created":"@1624642017.543487000","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":162}
I0625 13:26:57.543621000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:470]         TIMER 0x7fe314dce6f0: CANCEL pending=true
I0625 13:26:57.543689000 123145470926848 resource_quota.cc:954]        RQ anonymous_pool_140613267996560 ipv4:10.207.86.189:443: free 8192; free_pool -> 8192
I0625 13:26:57.543710000 123145470926848 subchannel.cc:1012]           Connect failed: {"created":"@1624642017.543487000","description":"Cannot check peer: missing selected ALPN property.","file":"src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_utils.cc","file_line":162}
I0625 13:26:57.543724000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:628]        chand=0x7fe31503d978: connectivity change for subchannel wrapper 0x7fe31505da50 subchannel 0x7fe31502e5e0; hopping into work_serializer
I0625 13:26:57.543730000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:663]        chand=0x7fe31503d978: processing connectivity change in work serializer for subchannel wrapper 0x7fe31505da50 subchannel 0x7fe31502e5e0 watcher=0x7fe314c783b0
I0625 13:26:57.543737000 123145470926848 subchannel_list.h:243]        [pick_first 0x7fe312ff0ee0] subchannel list 0x7fe313bb0010 index 1 of 2 (subchannel 0x7fe31505da50): connectivity changed: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE, shutting_down=0, pending_watcher=0x7fe314c783b0
I0625 13:26:57.543743000 123145470926848 subchannel_list.h:330]        [pick_first 0x7fe312ff0ee0] subchannel list 0x7fe313bb0010 index 1 of 2 (subchannel 0x7fe31505da50): canceling connectivity watch (connection attempt failed)
I0625 13:26:57.543843000 123145470926848 child_policy_handler.cc:87]   [child_policy_handler 0x7fe314ca0ba0] started name re-resolving
I0625 13:26:57.543854000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:1010]       chand=0x7fe31503d978: started name re-resolving
D0625 13:26:57.543860000 123145470926848 dns_resolver_ares.cc:410]     (c-ares resolver) resolver:0x7fe3136bdb40 In cooldown from last resolution (from 501 ms ago). Will resolve again in 29499 ms
I0625 13:26:57.543865000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:367]         TIMER 0x7fe3136bdc10: SET 30002 now 503 call 0x7fe3136bdbb8[0x104fe3100]
I0625 13:26:57.543870000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:404]           .. add to shard 0 with queue_deadline_cap=1001 => is_first_timer=false
I0625 13:26:57.543883000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:995]        chand=0x7fe31503d978: update: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE status=(UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses) picker=0x7fe3123f8450
I0625 13:26:57.543889000 123145470926848 connectivity_state.cc:156]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x7fe31503daa0]: CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE (helper, UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses)
I0625 13:26:57.543895000 123145470926848 connectivity_state.cc:164]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x7fe31503daa0]: notifying watcher 0x7fe313e80de0: CONNECTING -> TRANSIENT_FAILURE
I0625 13:26:57.543913000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2988]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: LB pick returned FAILED (subchannel=0x0, error={"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14})
I0625 13:26:57.543918000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2894]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: removing from queued picks list
I0625 13:26:57.543929000 123145470926848 subchannel_list.h:310]        [pick_first 0x7fe312ff0ee0] subchannel list 0x7fe313bb0010 index 0 of 2 (subchannel 0x7fe31250b640): starting watch (from TRANSIENT_FAILURE)
I0625 13:26:57.544040000 123145470926848 subchannel.cc:957]            Subchannel 0x7fe3150470a0: Retry in 570 milliseconds
I0625 13:26:57.544054000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:367]         TIMER 0x7fe3150471e8: SET 1073 now 503 call 0x7fe315047218[0x105007ed0]
I0625 13:26:57.544059000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:404]           .. add to shard 7 with queue_deadline_cap=1001 => is_first_timer=false
I0625 13:26:57.544063000 123145470926848 connectivity_state.cc:144]    ConnectivityStateTracker client_channel[0x7fe31503daa0]: remove watcher 0x7fe313e80de0
I0625 13:26:57.544072000 123145470926848 timer_generic.cc:470]         TIMER 0x7fe314dc3430: CANCEL pending=true
I0625 13:26:57.544090000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2926]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: failed to pick subchannel: error={"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544097000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2617]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: failing 1 pending batches: {"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544229000 123145470926848 completion_queue.cc:705]      cq_end_op_for_next(cq=0x7fe314cf4620, tag=0x7fe3123f4d80, error="No Error", done=0x104fa0020, done_arg=0x7fe314dc3380, storage=0x7fe314dc33a0)
I0625 13:26:57.544245000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2869]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: cancelling queued pick: error={"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]} self=0x7fe30e128340 calld->pick_canceller=0x0
D0625 13:26:57.544252000 123145470926848 call.cc:745]                  set_final_status CLI
D0625 13:26:57.544256000 123145470926848 call.cc:746]                  {"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544269000 123145470926848 completion_queue.cc:790]      cq_end_op_for_pluck(cq=0x7fe31491c470, tag=0x7ffeecf781c8, error="No Error", done=0x1050e2b70, done_arg=0x7fe30d363970, storage=0x7fe30d3639b8)
I0625 13:26:57.544281000 123145470926848 call.cc:638]                  OP[client-channel:0x7fe30d3637d0]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544287000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:1949]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 calld=0x7fe30d3637f0: recording cancel_error={"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544293000 123145470926848 dynamic_filters.cc:66]        OP[dynamic_filter_termination:0x7fe30d363b20]:  CANCEL:{"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544426000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2708]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: recording cancel_error={"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544301000 4438261184 completion_queue.cc:1319]          RETURN_EVENT[0x7fe31491c470]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x7ffeecf781c8 OK
I0625 13:26:57.544439000 123145470926848 client_channel.cc:2617]       chand=0x7fe31503d978 lb_call=0x7fe30d363ba0: failing 0 pending batches: {"created":"@1624642017.543918000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1624642017.543874000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}
I0625 13:26:57.544476000 123145470926848 resource_quota.cc:554]        RU shutdown 0x7fe314dc3600
```

Downversioning the `grpc` gem to `1.17.0` is successful (but requires ruby before `2.6`).

We are investigating if there is a server side problem with accepting ALPN.

Also the arguments to the `GRPC::Core::ChannelCredentials.new` constructor had the cert and key reversed.  (Changed from edit in code above.)

Comment: Could it be that your certs only include `grpc-server.cisco.com` SAN (used by `gRPCurl`) and not `grpc-server` (used by your Ruby client)? Perhaps try with `grpc-server.cisco.com:443` in your Ruby client too?

Comment: I'll look at that.  I scrubbed the hostname for the SO question.

Comment: Perhaps grab the server's logs too in order to see the server's response.

Comment: I'm working on that.  There is another team we have to co-ordinate with who are developing the server side.